# Cannot list files inside selected folder on Android

Tags: android, flutter

First I let the user pick a directory:

```dart
// file_picker package
final directoryPath = await FilePicker.platform.getDirectoryPath();
```

Then I want to list the contents:

```dart
void listFilesAndDirectories(String directoryPath) {
  try {
    final directory = Directory(directoryPath);
    List<FileSystemEntity> entities = directory.listSync(recursive: true);

    for (FileSystemEntity entity in entities) {
      if (entity is File) {
        print('File: ${entity.path}');
      } else if (entity is Directory) {
        print('Directory: ${entity.path}');
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error while listing files and directories: $e');
  }
}
```

I set `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` and these permissions are given:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The problem is that `listFilesAndDirectories` only lists containing directories. Files are missing. I use Android 13 (Samsung Galaxy S21)